# PhpMyAdmin SQL query table where the rows with same name has date before certain date AND after certain date

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I've just installed WAMP server in my Windows 10 computer and I'm playing around with it to learn how to query SQL table. So I make a case which I don't know how to query it. I've searched if my question is a duplicate question in this site, but since my limited English - I can't find questions in this site which the same like mine.

My table name is test. And it look something like this in PhpMyAdmin :
[image]

The query in ordinary language is something like this :
*show the rows which name has TGL before 2020/01/01 and has TGL after 2022/02/01*

So the expected result is the one which I mark red color: 
[image]

From questions in this site which is similar to my question is to query the table using `NOT BETWEEN` and using `< or >`. So I try that question's answer like this in PhpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE TGL < "2020/01/01" OR TGL > "2022/02/01"
```

another try using NOT BETWEEN

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE TGL NOT BETWEEN "2020/01/01" AND "2022/02/01"
```

But the query result (logically) is including another row (CCC) which has TGL before 2020/01/01 or has TGL after 2022/02/01 (BBB). Like the image below :

[image]

Playing illogical, so I also try to make the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE TGL < "2020/01/01" AND TGL > "2022/02/01"
```

And the query result show an empty row.

As per the answer to my question, so I try :

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE TGL NOT BETWEEN "2020/01/01" AND "2022/02/01" GROUP BY NAMA
```

But the query result is like this:
[image]

Since I still can't find the question in this site like mine, I'd be glad if someone can give me a link for duplicate question - so I can delete this question.

But if there is no duplicate question like mine, how do I query the date to get the expected result ?

Any kind of respond would be much appreciated. 
Thank you in advanced.

---

Edit

For the time being I make a solution in a silly way which I think maybe it's a bad way (not good to do that in the case like mine because there is another way which is better) in the eye of the experts. From the internet I've found, there is a method called nested query, a query which use another query result. So I use this method.

```
select * from test WHERE NAMA IN
(SELECT distinct NAMA FROM test WHERE NAMA IN
(SELECT DISTINCT NAMA from test where TGL < "2020/01/01")
and (TGL > "2022/02/01"))
AND (TGL < "2020/01/01" or TGL > "2022/02/01")
```

Although the query above give me the expected result, I still wonder if there is another way which is the proper way to do.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing. You are using this query correctly and its returning the required result:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE TGL < "2020/01/01" OR TGL > "2022/02/01"
```

Why do you not want the row 'B004' and 'C001' because they are both fulfilling the requirement?

`'B004' has TGL after 2022/02/01`

`'C001' has TGL before 2020/01/01`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Hazik. But I'm sorry, the result is still not that I'm expecting.